# Mypy type narrowing with recursive generic types

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, strong-typing

Let's say I make a generic class whose objects only contain one value (of type T).

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class Contains(Generic[T]):
    val: T
    def __init__(self, val: T):
        self.val = val
```

Note that self.val can itself be a Contains object, so a recursive structure is possible. I want to define a function that will reduce such a structure to a single non-Contains object.

```
def flatten(x):
    while isinstance(x, Contains):
        x = x.val
    return x
```

**What should the type signature of 'flatten' be?**

I tried to make a recursive Nested type

```
Nested = T | Contains['Nested[T]']
```

but it confuses the type checker as T can also mean a Contains object.

```
def flatten(x: Nested[T]) -> T:
    while isinstance(x, Contains):
        reveal_type(x) # reveals Contains[Unknown] | Contains[Nested]
        x = x.val
    reveal_type(x) # reveals object* | Unknown
    return x
```

Another approach was to make a separate class

```
class Base(Generic[T]):
    self.val: T
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val


Nested = Base[T] | Contains['Nested[T]']

def flatten(x: Nested[T]) -> T:
    while isinstance(x, Contains):
        x = x.val
    return x.val
```

This works, but you have to wrap the argument in a Base object every time, which is cumbersome. Furthermore, Base has the same behaviour as Contains, it's the same thing written twice! I tried to use NewType instead, but it isn't subscriptable.

Is there any nice (or, at least not too ugly) way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `Protocol` instead of `Generic` and making `val` a property of the protocol? That seems to be closer to what [mypy has documented](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#recursive-protocols).

Comment: @kojiro This doesn't make sense with the current structure of the class. Contains class isn't recursive by itself, that is, Contains objects don't necessarily containt other Contains objects inside, unlike TreeLike presented in mypy documentation, or a linked list. Sadly, it also doesn't solve the problem, the type checker still can't infer the correct type of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that static type checkers are typically unable to infer dynamic type changes from assignments such as:

```
x = x.val
```

As a workaround you can make `flatten` a recursive function instead to avoid an assignment to `x`:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, TypeAlias

T = TypeVar('T')

class Contains(Generic[T]):
    val: T
    def __init__(self, val: T):
        self.val = val

Nested: TypeAlias = T | Contains['Nested[T]']

def flatten(x: Nested[T]) -> T:
    if isinstance(x, Contains):
        return flatten(x.val)
    reveal_type(x) # Type of "x" is "object*"
    return x
```

Demo with PyRight [here](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAqiApgGoCGIANFAOLErEhIDGNRCxAggDZLkBnALAAoUQSgBeQiQogAFAHICigJSjRLHoIFQAwmBQxyqAfPqNmLANoEAuqoBcoqK6gA3cj0eEXbgCbEwFAA%2BiGoSDBh8gLEPMA0nt6ETn5ubrHxAHRJUh5eGiIAcsQCMMT%2BPhzcfIJ5EgA%2B%2BobGptaKJWUVtnaKdoWBwcDaMOUo8gAePp3l-j2qUAC0AHyEziLpSMFIAqbGKCzEkzQGRiYoAqkb6W4gxDAAriAoUMPkowyTOV7q16537mIXhC8E4k1%2B6Tuj2eUAmQA)

Demo with mypy [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=465fd824862aef746a7d284798412069)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Shame you have to write the function recursively, I wouldn't really want to sacrifice that much of performance for a simple type-check.